# Why does ExtJS not allow me to edit these combo boxes?

Tags: combobox, extjs4

OK, I have a `grid panel` in `ExtJS 4.0.2` that has one column that is a combobox.  The combobox allows me to select the populated data just fine.  But I want the user to be able to override the data-driven values in the combo with their own edited text.   However, when I type anything in the combo, it blanks out.  I can only select what's in the combo.  Period.

Here is my model and store:

```
Ext.define('modResolutions', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
    {
        name:    'resolution',
        type:    'string'
    }]
});

this.stoResolutions = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    data : [],
    listeners:  {
        add: function(store, record, index) {
        },
        datachanged: function(store) {
        },
        update: function(store, record, operation) {
        }
    },
    model: 'modResolutions',
    storeId: 'stoResolutions'
});
```

Here is my column:

```
{
    dataIndex:  'resolution',
    field: {
        allowBlank:       true,
        dataIndex:        'resolution',
        displayField:     'resolution',
        editable:         true,
        emptyText:        'Enter a resolution',
        listeners: {
            beforequery: function(obj) {

            },
            select: function(combo, records, opts) {
            }
        },
        listWidth:        500,
        maxLength:        255,                       
        maxLengthText:    'Limited to 255 characters',
        msgTarget:        'side',                    
        queryMode:        'local',
        readOnly:         false,
        store:            stoResolutions,
        title:            'Enter a resolution',
        valueField:       'resolution',
        xtype:            'combobox'
    },
    header:     'Resolution',
    renderer: function(value) {
        return value;
    },
    valueField: 'resolution',
    width:      200
}
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like [forceSelection](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox-cfg-forceSelection) is set to true, but I can't see it in your code. Do you have any overrides on the ComboBox class?

Comment: @Marko Nope.  I haven't overridden the combobox class.  Well, that I know of.  lol.  But I've checked the `editor` on that column and `forceSelection` is false and `editable` is true.

Comment: Try taking the renderer out of your column config, that may be doing it.

Answer (score -1):

Add forceSelection:false in combo box property